# mysql - conditions in on vs conditions in where

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, where-clause

I can't find a clear answer to this and my tests where inconclusive:

If I have a column in a table in a join that must be equal to (or in another relation with) a constant, is faster to put the condition in ON? Or at the end in WHERE?

Example:

```
    SELECT * FROM `" . BLABLA . "` as `s`
    JOIN `" . BLABLABLA . "` AS `sDet` ON (`sDet`.`a` > '" . $R['a'] . "'
        AND '" . $R['b'] . "' BETWEEN `sDet`.`c` AND `sDet`.`d`
        AND `s`.`id` = `sDet`.`idDet`
    )
    WHERE `s`.`f` = 'whatever'
```

Or

```
    SELECT * FROM `" . BLABLA . "` as `s`
    JOIN `" . BLABLABLA . "` AS `sDet` ON (`s`.`id` = `sDet`.`idDet`)
    WHERE `s`.`f` = 'whatever'
        AND '" . $R['b'] . "' BETWEEN `sDet`.`c` AND `sDet`.`d`
        AND `s`.`id` = `sDet`.`idDet`
```

I was thinking first version should be faster but I'm not sure. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whats quicker but do keep in mind that conditions are not always interchangeable between the where and on clause.

**Inner join**
In case of an INNER JOIN they are interchangable

**Outer join**
In case of an OUTER JOIN they are not necessarily interchangeable. It depends on which side of the join the conditions depends

Comment: That's correct... but is no issue in my case :). What I need to do is optimize that query (well... not that one but a similar one, with 9 joins).